# What's the difference between "Job Duration" and "Batch Processing Time" in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The job duration of my application in Spark UI is as below: 
[Job Duration in Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE80a.png)

And here is the batch processing time in Spark UI: 
[Batch Processing Time in Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUTHS.png)

Note that the batch processing time is generally longer than job duration. So, what is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark processes all the jobs in a batch together to utilize CPU time better. That is why batch processing times are greater than the jobs processing time.

Comment: Oh, but in my application, one batch corresponds to a single job, then what made the difference?